# How do I manually accelerate the rotation of a sphere in Unity 3D?

Tags: unity, physics

I'm a little new to this so any help will be appreciated.

---

**Context:**
I'm creating a VR billiard/pool game and trying to get the physics as realistic as possible. I have a cue ball being hit with a cue across a surface with accurate friction values calculated from real world trials.

---

**Problem:**
The angular acceleration of the balls isn't realistic at all. Therefore the angular velocity is off (this is due to how Unity calculates physics of interaction as a point of contact rather than an area of contact and therefore friction calculation is done at one point causing it to rotate slower).

---

**Question:**
How can I manually set the angular acceleration to a value in code until the angular acceleration is greater than or equals to horizontal velocity, then the angular acceleration is set to 0? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For reference for others, this is an extension of an earlier question: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/185158/how-do-i-manually-change-a-sliding-ball-into-a-rolling-ball-in-unity-3d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity doesn't have an 'angular acceleration' field that you can set. You can set the [angular velocity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-angularVelocity.html) in code, as I showed in your previous question about this. If you need to accelerate or decelerate the angular velocity, you can do this manually in your code.

```
void Update() {
    if (rigidbody.angularVelocity.magnitude < desiredAngularVelocity) {
        //scales the acceleration each frame
        rigidbody.angularVelocity = rigidbody.angularVelocity * accelerationRate * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

or if you want the angular velocity to change by a constant rate rather than scaling it, I think this will work (haven't tested it):

```
void Update() {
    if (rigidbody.angularVelocity.magnitude < desiredAngularVelocity) {
        float angularSpeed = rigidBody.angularVelocity.magnitude;
        angularSpeed += acceleration * Time.deltaTime;
        rigidbody.angularVelocity = rigidbody.angularVelocity.normalized * angularSpeed;
    }
}
```

Or if you want to use forces, try `rigidbody.`[AddTorque()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html)

```
rigidbody.AddTorque(transform.right * 10000);
```

This is more complicated because torque is 3D; you'll have to calculate the correct direction for the torque.

You may wish to review [all of the functions available to Rigidbodies](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html).

Comment: Isn't `Time.deltaTime` simple the time between frames? Did you mean to have a timer in place indicating the time passed?

Comment: @NedSunshine Yes, `Time.deltaTime` is the amount of time that elapsed over the last frame. In my simple example, multiplying the acceleration rate by `Time.deltaTime` ensures that the acceleration is smooth even if the application framerate is inconsistent.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing something. This and what I tried before don't accelerate the rotation. Wouldn't I expect this to cause the ball to rotate/roll faster over time? (ignoring the if statement)

Comment: Yes. Try adding `Debug.Log("before: " + rigidbody.angularVelocity)` before you change the velocity and `Debug.Log("after: " + rigidbody.angularVelocity)` after you change it; this may help you understand what's going on.

Comment: I found the root of the problem. It's the default limit of 7 to the angular velocity. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-maxAngularVelocity.html

Comment: @NedSunshine Good catch, I forgot about that limit.